# Completion of $\sigma$-algbera is closed under complementation

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading Donald L.Cohn's "Measure Theory" and in p.31, Proposition 1.5.1 states:

> Let $(X, \mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathscr{A}$. Then $\mathscr{A}_\mu$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that includes $\mathscr{A}$, and $\overline{\mu}$ is a measure on $\mathscr{A}_\mu$ that is complete and whose restriction to $\mathscr{A}$ is $\mu$.

In the above proposition, $\mathscr{A}_\mu$ is called the completion of $\mathscr{A}$ and is defined as the collection of subsets $A$ of $X$ for which there are sets $E$ and $F$ in $\mathscr{A}$ such that $E\subseteq A\subseteq F$ and $\mu(F-E)=0$. The definition of  $\overline{\mu}$ is not relevant to my question.

In the proof of the above proposition the author proves that $\mathscr{A}_\mu$ is closed under complementation by stating that the relations $E\subseteq A\subseteq F$ and $\mu(F-E)=0$ imply the relations $F^c\subseteq A^c\subseteq E^c$ and $\mu(E^c-F^c)=0$.

My question is, why the relation $\mu(E^c-F^c)=0$ is implied? I understand why it is true for a finite measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ but I don't understand why it is true for a general measure space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $E^\complement - F^\complement = E^ \complement \cap (F^ \complement)^ \complement = E^ \complement \cap F = F - E$

Same sets, same measure...

Comment: Missed that obvious equality..